# Why is the default Object Page added by SAP Fiori Tools App Generator empty when using the "List Report Object Page" template?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, cds

This question applies to SAP Fiori Elements. I was wondering why the default Object Page contains no facets, field groups or fields when added by the "List Report Object Page" template.

The generated List Report is usually fine, but when I click on a record in the presented table, I expect to see the data on the Object Page. What could be the reason for the data not being added by default?